# Cannot import name 'market candles'

Tags: python, github, module

So i'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/icoprimers/pyttrex/blob/master/pyttrex/ADX.py) github repository, i put it on my site-packages folder and tested [this](https://github.com/icoprimers/pyttrex/blob/master/pyttrex/ADX.py) example, but i got the error `cannot import name 'market_candles'`. What could be causing this problem? I already made sure that TA-Lib, Pandas and Matplotlib are installed, so where could be the problem? I'm looking at the `__init__py` and it seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning the repository directly into your sites-packages will result in nested pyttrex folders. Copy only the `pyttrex/pyttrex` directory into sites-packages

```
pyttrex
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── pyttrex
│   ├── ADX.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── average_n
│   ├── average_true_range.py
│   ├── backtest.py
│   └── test.py
└── tgnotifier.py
```

Comment: So i deleted the other files and kept only pyttrex, stil got the error, could be some error which i'm missing from the code?